# Using wordnet in java

Tags: java, semantics, semantic-web, wordnet, jaws-wordnet

I am new to wordnet API and I am struggling how I can get to th following issue;

I would like that if I give for example "George Bush" I will arrive to the term person. The following diagram illustrates better from the online API:

[image]

Through the following code i managed to output the first stage, which is:

[Bush,George Bush,George W. Bush,George Walker Bush,President Bush,President George W. Bush,Dubyuh,Dubya] - 43rd President of the United States; son of George Herbert Walker Bush (born in 1946)

The code:

```
 WordNetDatabase database = WordNetDatabase.getFileInstance();
        Synset[] synsets = database.getSynsets("George Bush", SynsetType.NOUN);
        for (int i = 0; i < synsets.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(synsets[i]);
}
```

Any idea how I can arrive to the term "person"?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/About) for this purpose?

It will serve your purpose better, as it has the infoboxes which are extracted from Wikipedia. Its also available free for use.

(P.S : If I understand correctly, your purpose is to get the superclass of an entity.)